# CSS : grid-column and grid-row doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I Want to create a grid with the first column that contain mulitples row of text and the second column the same number of row of inputs. To do so i thought about doing just a grid of the number of raw = number of line of text and set the number of column that i need.

```
.AllScores{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 450px 200px auto 50px 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    grid-template-rows: 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}

.AllScores_text{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
    background-color: #289e19 ;
    text-align: right;
}

.AllScores_inputs{
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
    background-color: #199a9e ;
    text-align: left;
}
```

So AllScores is my "grid Container" and AllScores_text is just the first cell of the grid and  AllScores_inputs the second cell of the first row.

I'm just doing this to try something simple at first as i'm new with CSS and HTML, but my issue is that the grid-column/row-start/end doesn't work.
I also tried with just grid-column : and grid-row :  but it doesn't work either

I also need the flexibility of the grid for later : for now i could just use a table but later i would have merge some cells together and that's why i'm trying doing this with grid.

There is the HTML :

```
<div class='AllScores'>
    <form action="{{ actual_age_range }}/Scores_Gathered" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
        <div class='AllScores_text'>
            <label for="DM1_Pref_Hand">Score DM1 - Tirelire (Main préférée) : </label>
        </div>
        <div class='AllScores_inputs'>
            <input id="DM1_Pref_Hand" type="text" name='DM1_Pref_Hand' value="{{ DM1_PH }}">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Anyway, thanks for your help and your answers ^^

Comment: Please provide your HTML

Comment: Can you provide an image or HTML showing the desired outcome of your grid layout?

Comment: I had the HTML code and for the image, i just want for now the text in the first cell (first row, first column) and the input cell in the second one ( first row, 2nd column)

Comment: That `grid-template-rows` is making my eyes bleed, why can you not just `grid-template-rows: 30px` and leave it at that? You're not changing anything!

Comment: I need multiple rows. For this example i only need one but then i need at least 11. And 30px is just an random value to test things for now @ChloeAnderson

Comment: Yes but that changes nothing... you don't need to specify 30px over and over just because you  have more rows! They all are the same height!

Comment: @ChloeAnderson Ohh yeah i deleted the line and it's now much better ! I used all this 30px because i thought i had to specify it a number of time equals to number of rows i would like. But it just allocate by itself depending on "sub grid class" Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i have resolved my issue : if you look at my HTML, i use the class = 'AllScores' in the first div.
The issue was that then i have a form and then i was using my other div with the "element" of the grid.

What i mean is that, from what've learned, when you want to use a grid and then specify those column/row properties in a "sub grid class", this sub grid must be call directly in the grid container.

In my case i had :

```
<div class='AllScores'>
    <form>
        <div class='AllScores_text'>
            ...
        </div>
        <div class='AllScores_inputs'>
            ...
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And so as the class of the sub grid (AllScores_inputs and AllScores_text) where inside the form, that is itself inside the .

I needed to have the call of class='AllScores_inputs' just under the call of class = AllScores.

So those 2 options work : putting the class='AllScores' in the form :

```
<div>
    <form class='AllScores'>
        <div class='AllScores_text'>
            ...
        </div>
        <div class='AllScores_inputs'>
            ...
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

or switching the form and the div :

```
<form>
    <div class='AllScores'>
        <div class='AllScores_text'>
            ...
        </div>
        <div class='AllScores_inputs'>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first time, grid-column or grid-row it's a shorthand.
You must write the start of column/row and the end of column/row.
for example:

```
.AllScores_text {
grid-column: 1 /2;
grid-row: 1 / 2;
}
```

So the .AllScores_inputs doesn't work because it's missing the end of column and the end of the row.

And you can check with the inspect of element in the navigator internet to see the result.

I hope to help you.

Comment: Yeah that's what i've tried in the first place : ive tried the : 
```
grid-column: 1 /2;
grid-row: 1 / 2;
```
but also 
````
grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
````
and the one you see there with : grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1; but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The form is "display: block" by default. Change in css "display: grid".